# Application.Undo not working with calender popup in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need to retrieve the old date value and new date value, that I enter in a cell.

The code below works fine if I enter the date using the keyboard. But if I enter the date from a calendar popup, I get an error as

> "Method 'undo' of object '_application' failed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim newVal As String
    Dim oldVal As String

    newVal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value
                MsgBox (newVal)
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Application.Undo

    oldVal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value
                MsgBox (oldVal)
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value = newVal
                Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN Article:

> This method undoes only the last action taken by the user before running the macro, and it must be the first line in the macro. It cannot be used to undo Visual Basic commands.

You can only use `Application.Undo` to reverse **User** edits (i.e. typed in with the keyboard) - any edits made in code cannot be undone by this method, so if the cell's value is assigned as part of another piece of code, this method will not work.

Comment: Is there any alternative solution to reverse User edits -- typed in with  the keyboard as well as input using mouse?

Comment: You could look at using the `Worksheet_Change()` event with a public variable, but I'm not sure how you would distinguish between user actions and code actions...